# how to disable inArray validator forms in zend framework2

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2

i use this in my Form:

```
$this->add(array(     
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',       
    'name' => 'county',
    'registerInArrayValidator' => false,
    'attributes' =>  array(
        'id' => 'county',                
        'options' => array(
            //'null'=>'[Select county]',
        ),
    ),
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'county',
    ),
));
```

and set value county field with js.
after validation, i get error : haystack option is mandatory

Comment: Could you please improved the formatting of your question?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `registerInArrayValidator` only works for the ZF1. I would formulate the question a some abstractlier: How to remove a validator from the Form Element `ValidatorChain`? Have been debugging a bit and can actually not find and way to do this. Maybe somehow over the `ValidatorPluginManager` (`$form->getInputFilter()->get('myElement')->getValidatorChain()>getPluginManager()`)...

Comment: See the post of Alexander Ermakov (2012-10-15 17:15) [here](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/The-input-was-not-found-in-the-haystack-td4657596.html). He's extending the `Select` class and adding a new method `setInarray(...)`. Don't know iwhether it works, but you could try it out.

Comment: This can help you: `$formInputFilter = $form->getInputFilter();
$formInputFilter->remove('county');
$formInputFilter->add((new Zend\InputFilter\Factory())->createInput(array(
 'name'     => 'county',
 'required' => true,
)));` See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16252520/2019043) and Remi Thomas's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252520/how-to-remove-a-validator-from-a-form-element-form-element-validatorchain-in-z?noredirect=1#comment23254235_16252520). But for me it's a workaround, not a solution, I would be happy with.

Comment: thank u : @automatix . your code work .

Answer (score 10):

Add the disable_inarray_validator to the options:

```
$this->add(array(
    ...
    'options' => array(
        'disable_inarray_validator' => true,
        'label' => 'county',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2):

In https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Select.php
there is an option `$disableInArrayValidator = false`; and the corresponding method [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Select.php#L158)

Answer (score 0):

In ZF1, this is what works:

```
// using the element instance:
$element->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);

// or a configuration key as part of the options array:
'registerInArrayValidator' => false

// or
element.options.registerInArrayValidator = false
```